# Can you kill a gargantuan monster from within?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Imagine that a party manages somehow to get inside a dragon turtle without injury to themselves (we have some plans using magic, but that's not part of the question).

Once inside, could you kill it from within? Would the natural hazards of being inside a monster like the dragon turtle interfere with the plan, or could it be expected to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely injure a gargantuan monster from within; [it's actually the only way to get out of the Tarrasque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gct8.jpg) once swallowed, so using those same rules (your character is blinded, restrained, has total cover, and is taking acid damage every round), it should be possible to adapt this to other monsters.

However, the fact that your character has total coverage may cause some issues, depending on how you intend to use magic. Coverage from attack is also coverage from help.

For more rules on swallow, I actually found [a D&D Basic guide](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/DMDnDBasicRules_v0.1.pdf) that contains some handy rules you could use. Large Frogs and Large Toads, while smaller than Gargantuan, have rules for Swallow. The Tarrasque, while larger than Gargantuan, has similar rules for Swallow. It is thus logical that a Gargantuan creature would have similar rules along those lines.

Comment: Whether there's a sufficiently large (and appropriately-configured) cavity inside the creature for you to exist inside in is an open question; You'll have to ask your GM about (for example) the size and shape of dragon turtle lungs.