# Can I use Banishment to get inside the guts of a gargatuan monster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell *banishment* says in part

> If the target is native to the plane of existence you’re on, you banish the target to a harmless demiplane. While there, the target is incapacitated. The target remains there until the spell ends, at which point the target reappears in the space it left or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied.

Does the lung or stomach of a gargantuan monster (e.g., dragon turtle) count as an unoccupied space for the purpose of using *banishment* to transport myself into it?

Comment: @DrunkCynic Please note that comments are not for mini answers.

Comment: [Related] [Can you kill a gargantuan monster from within?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70712)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NO.

Any space that a monster is in, is occupied (that's definitional, the monster occupies it's own space). Even if you could normally move through the monster's space unencumbered, for the purposes of counting occupied space, it must actually be a clear space, not one occupied by a creature.

Comment: At this point, wouldn't he be "swallowed" by the creature?

Comment: No, because you can't use the power as intended. The space within the monster's gut isn't unoccupied, it's occupied.

Answer (score 0):

A space is considered occupied if a creature is currently inhabiting it -- so by RAW, no. However, the universe probably wouldn't make such a distinction -- ask your DM.